# open specific post, photos album or video from android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hey every one I wonder how can I open specific post, album or video from android app  in facebook app, I used this code to open specific post but it doesn't work

```
mActivity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
                    String uri = "fb://post/" + mData.get(position).getmPostID();
                    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(uri));
```

I want to open this post 
https://www.facebook.com/Y.Anti.coup.D/posts/707105232705409
Sorry for my bad English and I hope that you understand my problem